# Is there a Counter in Python that can accumulate negative values?

Tags: python, counter

I am using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) like this:

```
from collections import Counter

totals = Counter()
c_one = Counter(a=10, b=1)
c_two = Counter(a=10, b=-101)

totals += c_one
totals += c_two    

# Output: Counter({'a': 20})
print(totals)
```

Which is not at all what I expected. I expected to see:

```
Counter({'a': 20, 'b': -100})
```

Where did my negatives go, and is there some `Counter` that will let me use negatives?

Comment: I'm curious. What's with asking a question, then posting an answer *as somebody else* (i.e. "from the docs you linked"). *At the same time* ?

Comment: @SiHa I suppose that is a bit odd.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> The multiset methods are designed only for use cases with positive values. The inputs may be negative or zero, but **only outputs with positive values are created**. There are no type restrictions, but the value type needs to support addition, subtraction, and comparison.

<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

However, if you look a little closer you'll find [your answer](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update):

> Elements are counted from an iterable or added-in from another mapping (or counter). **Like dict.update() but adds counts instead of replacing them.** Also, the iterable is expected to be a sequence of elements, not a sequence of (key, value) pairs.

<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

All you have to do is make one tiny change, and your example will work:

```
from collections import Counter

totals = Counter()
c_one = Counter(a=10, b=1)
c_two = Counter(a=10, b=-101)

# Instead of totals += c_one; totals += c_two
totals.update(c_one)
totals.update(c_two)    

# Output: Counter({'a': 20, 'b': -100})
print(totals)
```